# react-router-dom doesn't work with node express back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am serving my react app as a static website which includes a react-router-dom, at first glance it all look ok but the I get not found if I refresh any of the pages in my app and for it to work again I need to go to the main page.

```
import express from 'express';
import app from './app';
import path from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
  });

}

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`)!);
```

...

```
<MiscProvider>
  <DataProvider>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/create' exact component={create} />
        <Route path='/viewer' exact component={viewer} />
        <Route path='/ready' exact component={ready} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </DatasProvider>
</MiscProvider>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, may be the problem is with having your code withing the `if` condition, may be something is weird with the env variables. Can you try moving the codeblock outside the `if` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried to use hash route , delete the if ... nothing works

Comment: which version of react-router are you on?

Comment: @ChristianFritz  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

Comment: @ChristianFritz there is somthing wrong with express I think why would everything work fine unless I refresh, in dev all works like butter

Comment: Do you mean that it's doing this when you deploy it, but not when you run locally? If so, have you deployed to netlify? That's a common problem, which you can see a solution to here https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa

Comment: @GordonMaloney actually to Heroku

Comment: See: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#heroku

Comment: @DrewReese hi drew, I solved it using a hash router which looks look with the # I looked at your reference and I am tiring the /* solution to see if its going to work. if it works i will tell you so you can post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `res.sendFile()` part, you are calling wrong the `path.join()`. The first time you come to the website on path `/`, it is working because in this case, and since there isn't a request handler set for this specific path, Express will look for an `index.html` inside your static folder (client/build).

You could do so:

```js
import express from 'express';
import app from './app';
import path from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    // here where you were doing wrong
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
  });

}

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`)!);
```